# Finding all parents from node to the root in a tree by recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have a class Graph, modelling a Tree. Graph contain a pointer `Graph*` to the parent of my current instance (my current node).

```
class Graph
{
private:

    Graph* parent;
public:
    Graph* getparent();
}

Graph* Graph::getparent()
{
    return this->parent;
}
```

parent is at `nullptr` if root.

I'm trying to find the distance from a node to the root, starting from the node.

Here is my try :

```
int Graph::howManyParents(Graph* unparent)
{
    int nbParents(0);
    if(unparent != nullptr)
    {
        nbParents++;
        nbParents =+ howManyParents(this->parent);
    }
    return nbParents;
}
```

It compiles but crashes. Debugger show me lots of call to the method, but end up SegFaulting. Is there something wrong with my algorithm ?

Comment: May I ask what you think the "operator" `=+` does?

Comment: It's an assignment operator and a unary plus operator :)

Comment: And the second question: Is `howManyParents` method a member of `Graph` class? (This is not obvious from class declaration)

Comment: Are you trying to find the distance from `unparent`, as the fact that it's a parameter suggests, or from `this`, as your recursion suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion never stops unless you pass it the root, as you're always calling `this->howManyParents` and thus passing it the same parent, which won't become null.

It is unclear whether you want the distance from the parameter or the distance from `this`.

Finding the distance from a given node (there is no reason for this to be a member):

```
int howManyParents(Graph* unparent)
{
    int nbParents(0);
    if(unparent != nullptr)
    {
        nbParents = howManyParents(unparent->getparent()) + 1;
    }
    return nbParents;
}
```

Finding the distance from `this`:

```
int Graph::howManyParents()
{
    int nbParents(0);
    if(parent != nullptr)
    {
        nbParents = parent->howManyParents() + 1;
    }
    return nbParents;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are causing stack overflow with too deep or infinite recursion.

Check your input for errors to ensure it is really a tree, because recursion will be infinite in case of a loop in the graph.

Also, try to increase stack size of your program.

On linux just run the command:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

To do it in Microsoft Visual C++ just add this line to the code:

```
#pragma comment(linker, '/STACK:67108864');
```

To do it in MinGW G++ add this option to compilation line:

```
-Wl,--stack,67108864
```

But, I think non-recursive solution is overall better here.

```
int Graph::howManyParents(Graph* unparent)
{
    int nbParents(0);
    while (unparent != nullptr)
    {
        nbParents++;
        unparent = unparent->parent;
    }
    return nbParents;
}
```

It is better to use loops instead of recursion where it is possible to improve both performance and code readability.

Only use recursion where it is really needed. To traverse the tree, for example.

Comment: Ah, you're right, an iterative method was way much easier. Thank you Didn't tought about it... I don't think i have loop in my graph. It's really a tree, that's sure, but when i use BFS, i test to avoid nodes that were already seen.

Comment: Your non-recursive "solution" has the same bug as the original recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
int Graph::howManyParents()
{
    return getparent() ? getparent()->howManyParents() + 1 : 0;
}
```

Also don't forget to write the constructor which makes your `parent = nullptr`, it's not by default constructor.